# Automatically hit a web application deployed with TFS

Tags: .net, iis, deployment, tfs-2015

We use `VS TFS 2015` for CI and deploy a web application (.net) to Dev or Prod server.
 As for all web applications hosted in IIS, the first access to the website after the deployment is very slow.

I used Octopus Deploy and it was possible to check the deployed website to return a specific code, hence it would have triggered the first access automatically.

Is there something equivalent with TFS?

At the moment, my idea would be to use a power shell as last task inside of the my release definition for that project to hit the website URL. In this way the application pool would immediately trigger the build of the libraries after the deployment. Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

There might be an extension in the TFS marketplace to do this (I haven't looked), but the powershell script is probably your best option.  It's ridiculously simple.